# Julia - Generate 2-matching odd Set

Tags: optimization, graph, set, julia, time-complexity

In Julia, given a `Set{Tuple{Int, Int}}` named `S` of length greater than 3, for instance:

```
julia> S = Set{Tuple{Int,Int}}([(1, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 6)])
Set{Tuple{Int64,Int64}} with 4 elements:
  (2, 5)
  (3, 6)
  (2, 6)
  (1, 4)
```

I want to return a subset `T` of `S` of length greater than `3` and odd (3, 5, 7, ...) such that, all first values of the tuples are unique. For instance, I can't have (2, 5) and (2, 6) because first value, 2 will not be unique. The same applies for second values meaning that I can't have (2, 6) and (3, 6).

If it is not possible, returning an empty Set of Tuple is fine.

Finally for the above minimal example the code should return:

```
julia> T = Set{Tuple{Int,Int}}([(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)])
Set{Tuple{Int64,Int64}} with 3 elements:
  (2, 5)
  (3, 6)
  (1, 4)
```

I am truly open to any other type of strucutre if you think it is better than `Set{Tuple{Int, Int}}` :)

I know how I can do it with integer programming. However, I will run this many times with large instances and I would like to know if there is a better way because I deeply think it can be done in polynomial time and perhaps in Julia with clever `map` or other efficient functions!

Comment: It does not seem that your problem has a unique solution to me. (I mean, it has in the instance you provided, but I don't think it has in general.). So what should happen in case there are many solutions? Should it compute all of them?

Comment: @BenoitPasquier, yes I wrote that I want to return a subset `T` of `S`, meaning, when several exist, return any that matches the conditions. However, although I am not sure, I'm still working on it, I am conjecturing that the smallest ones would be the best :) For a start, return any of the ones that exist is enough and great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a way to filter the possible combinations of members of a set. So create a filtering function. If the part about an odd [3, 5, 7...] sequence you mentioned applies here, somehow, you might need to add that to the filter logic below:

```
using Combinatorics

allunique(a) = length(a) == length(unique(a))
slice(tuples, position) = [t[position] for t in tuples]
uniqueslice(tuples, position) = allunique(slice(tuples, position))
is_with_all_positions_unique(tuples) = all(n -> uniqueslice(tuples, n), 1:length(first(tuples)))
```

Now you can find combinations.  With big sets these will explode in number, so make sure to exit when you have enough.  You could use Lazy.jl here, or just a function:

```
function tcombinations(tuples, len, needed)
    printed = 0
    for combo in combinations(collect(tuples), len)
        if is_with_all_positions_unique(combo)
            printed += 1
            println(combo)
            printed >= needed && break
        end
    end
end

tcombinations(tuples, 3, 4)

[(2, 5), (4, 8), (3, 6)]
[(2, 5), (4, 8), (1, 4)]
[(2, 5), (4, 8), (5, 6)]
[(2, 5), (3, 6), (1, 4)]
```